# Jupyter files won't load unless I refresh multiple times

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When I click on an ipynb file in Jupyter, a new tab opens but is completely blank. Nothing appears unless I manually refresh the browser page at least twice.

Comment: Same to me, can you provide what chrome extension you installed?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Jupyter lab instead of Jupyter notebook. It'll load smoothly in lab.